# PlayFramework java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I have a basic playframwork2/scala application that works fine locally.

Once exported to my lunix/apache server, it is a different story.(I use dist to deploy)

As soon as I load a page that contains an image, the application stops, and I get this error:

`Uncaught error from thread [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14]: unable to create new native thread, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[application]`
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread`

My server has a reverse proxy configured this way:

`ProxyRequests Off`

`ProxyPass / http://serverUrl.net:30000/`

`ProxyPassReverse / http://serverUrl.net:30000/`

Has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23918084/14700140

I used the following command to increase the number of processes available for my application:

`>prlimit --pid 864 --nproc=1000`